# How to return raw value instead of relationship object in a laravel collection

Tags: laravel, collections, backend, transform

I'm struggling to get a relationship value in a LengthAwarePaginator object, I'm trying to get the name of the record creator using the collection `transform` method and overriding the `created_by` attribute, but I'm getting the whole object and not only the name:

```
    $data = $this->smsTemplateRepository->getAll($page, $pageSize, $filter, $sortBy, $paginate);
    $data->transform(function ($item, $key) {
          $item['created_by'] = $item->createdBy->name;
          return $item;
    });
```

and this is what I'm getting in the frontend

```
code: "eS5Zx39jXq"
created_at: "2022-05-13T15:55:39.000000Z"
created_by: {id: 2, legacy_user_ref: "bece66c5efe01a4a4fae87650f1072a9", user_type: "employee", client_id: null,…}
id: 5
message: "lIu72gF7S4 {{ worker_name }}2SiQPJAgFrzMw1fzPfqtGSYLY4hgzC1ZOBFaKQGG8T21VSWjmn bye."
name: "fb71e78X07 rQ7ChsUQNr"
sms_legacy_ref: "H6O1BxFBDT"
updated_at: "2022-05-13T15:55:39.000000Z"
updated_by: 2
```

I'm expecting `created_by: 'Name Lastname',`

Any ideas, Thanks!!

Comment: What is the method `through()` that you're using ? it's not a collection method, what does getAll() return ?

Comment: @N69S sorry, the method is transform, and the result of the getAll method is a LengthAwarePaginator object given by: 
$query = $this->smsTemplateModel->query();
$query = $this->addFilterToQuery($query, $filter);
$query = $this->addSortingToQuery($query, $sortBy);
return $query->paginate($pageSize);

Comment: just replace the line with `$item->createdBy = $item->createdBy->name;`

Comment: that will create the createdBy attribute with the right value, but will leave the whole create record which is no the expected:
...
code: "uc8NGasN9c"
createdBy: "Juli Raigosa"
created_at: "2022-05-13T15:55:39.000000Z"
created_by: {id: 2, legacy_user_ref: "bece66c5efe01a4a4fae87650f1072a9", user_type: "employee", client_id: null,…}
...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unload the relation once you set the attribute you want

```
$data = $this->smsTemplateRepository->getAll($page, $pageSize, $filter, $sortBy, $paginate);
    $data->transform(function ($item, $key) {
          $createdBy = $item->createdBy->name;
          $item->unsetRelation('createdBy');
          $item->created_by = $createdBy;
          return $item;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, my man! just what I needed!